# R: Plot of frequency of features per class

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the matrix below:

```
r= 50
c = 10
testdata <- matrix(rbinom(r*c,1,0.5),r,c)
examplev <- rep(c(290,320,390,460,520,580,710,780,800,100001),5)
testdata <- cbind(testdata,examplev)
```

Say each binary column stands for a feature and the last column in the classes of data. I want to create a plot that shows features 1 to 10 on the y axis and the classes one to ten on the x axis showing how many of my data records including feature y are a member of class x. Any idea how to write the code in R?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to map the curves of each of your data?  Could you be looking for violin plots?  http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html

Comment: Your comment also helped. I had never heard of violin plots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% what you asked for because I am using bar charts instead of density plots,  but this is close to what you want.

```
TABLE = sapply(as.data.frame(testdata[,1:10]), 
    function(x) table(x, testdata[,11])[2,])

## You will need to stretch the graphics window horizontally
par(mfrow=c(1, 10))
for(i in 1:10) { 
    barplot(TABLE[i,], horiz=TRUE, xlim=c(0,max(TABLE)), 
        las=1, xlab=rownames(TABLE)[i])
```

}

[image: Boxplots]